# MSAL Azure Ad authentication get access token for One Note Resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to get access token for microsoft graph api as well as One note while SSO login.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        // The `Authority` represents the v2.0 endpoint - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0
                        Authority = AuthenticationConfig.Authority,
                        ClientId = AuthenticationConfig.ClientId,
                        
                        RedirectUri = AuthenticationConfig.RedirectUri,
                        PostLogoutRedirectUri = AuthenticationConfig.RedirectUri,
                        Scope = AuthenticationConfig.BasicSignInScopes + " Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.Read.Selected Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Files.ReadWrite.Selected Notes.Create Notes.Read Notes.Read.All Notes.ReadWrite Notes.ReadWrite.All Notes.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp User.Read User.Read.All", // a basic set of permissions for user sign in & profile access "openid profile offline_access"
                        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = false,
                            // In a real application you would use IssuerValidator for additional checks, like making sure the user's organization has signed up for your app.
                            //IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, tvp) =>
                            //{
                            //         if(mycustomtenantvalidation(issuer))
                            //         return issuer;
                            //         else
                            //             throw new securitytokeninvalidissuerexception("invalid issuer");
                            //     },
                            //NameClaimType = "name",
                        },
                        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                        {
                            AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                        },
                        // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/owin-samesite
                        CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(
                                         new SystemWebCookieManager())
```

The access token I am getting is working for One drive only. For one note getting **request does not contain valid access token**

**Getting Access Token:-**

```
 private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
        {
            // Upon successful sign in, get the access token & cache it using MSAL
            IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
            AuthenticationResult result = await clientApp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(new[] { "Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.Read.Selected Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Files.ReadWrite.Selected Notes.Create Notes.Read Notes.Read.All Notes.ReadWrite Notes.ReadWrite.All Notes.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp User.Read User.Read.All" }, context.Code).ExecuteAsync();
             var code = context.Code;
             
        }
```

I have checked that we need to pass the resource id for one note while login. But I am not getting where to pass that.

Comment: It seems that the problem is on the `scope`. `Notes.Create` ...  permissions about onenote of your application are under MS Graph or under OneNote?

Comment: They are present in graph as well as for one note.

Comment: Can you share the code which calls one note?